# Save column width for extended datatable

Tags: richfaces, jsf-1.2

I am using Richfaces 3.3. I have an extended datatable for which I need to save the state for every user individually. This includes the column width(which are adjustable). Every user can re-size the width of the columns by simply dragging the column borders horizontally. Next time the user logs in then the same column widths should be visible to him as he had set. I do not find any good examples for the tableState. Please help.

Comment: Not explored by myself, but logically I think you could load/save theses informations by yourself using `binding` attribute from the table.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie: Agreed, but what events would be catching the width change for the extended datatable? Because when I check for the width of the columns while saving the data, the values remain unchanged. :(

Comment: In that case, I suggest usage of jQuery in combination with `a4j:jsFunction`, you will be able to send JavaScript values to the bean for example, after resize. Of course that will not be simple!